# Chrome how to do I create prompt dialog to install an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I ran into this the other day, a website was able to prompt to install a chrome extension, without me having to leave the site and go to the chrome web store:

[image]

How can you accomplish this for an extension, instead of directing users to the extension page on the chrome store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears you basically (associate your website with the extension then) call a chrome callback as the result of an onclick action:

```
chrome.webstore.install(url, successCallback, failureCallback)
```

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation

You may also want to decorate your website, it suggests in that link to have a button "add to chrome" or what not (in the example image, they add some directions text).

example:

in

```
 <head> <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ionkpaepibbmmhcijkhmamakpeclkdml">
 </head>
 ...
 <input type="submit" value="Clicking here" onclick="installExtension(); return false;"/>
  <script>
    function installExtension() {chrome.webstore.install("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ionkpaepibbmmhcijkhmamakpeclkdml", 
         function() { console.log("installed it");}, function() { console.log("rejected it");}); 
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore

Comment: True enough, now you can just link to the extension in the chrome web store.  And have its images and text prompt with install instructions...